# PHP reading csv, issue with double quotes

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I have a csv file that has 6 lines like the following :

```
10264,dan,Dan,37519,MILLER,6/3/2014 14:51,$28.40,Rapid,Dan@Cold.com,,
10443,Dari,"D. R, LLC",37308,SELLERS,6/2/2014 15:12,$40.00,esponse,chards@lobal.net,,
10488,EmHern,"A HOME FOR YOU,LLC",37749,MILLER,6/1/2014 8:23,$33.00, Response,23@YAHOO.COM,,
```

I trying to read that csv and extract some columns then add a pipe delimiter to each column extracted, here is the function I used :

```
<?php
function fncReadCSV($csvFileName){
    $result = array();
    $row = 1;
    if (($handle = fopen($csvFileName, "r")) !== FALSE) {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                $outPut = "";
                $outPut .= $data[0];
                $outPut .="|";
                $outPut .= $data[1];
                $outPut .="|";  
                $outPut .= $data[2];
                $outPut .="|";  
                $outPut .= $data[6];
                $outPut .="|";  
                $outPut .= $data[8];
                $outPut .="|";                                  
                array_push($result, rtrim($outPut, "|"));
                $row++;
            }               
           }
    fclose($handle);
    return $result;
    }
echo "<pre>";
print_r(fncReadCSV("file.csv"));
echo "</pre>";
```

the result I get is correct for only the first  row, for the 2nd, 3rd rows I get the full row as it is in the csv, I'm expecting the quotes to break my code how can I fix that with a code that works for csv files with quotes present and csv files without please?

the result is :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10264|dan|Dan|$28.40|Dan@Cold.com
    [1] => 10443,Dari,"D. R, LLC",37308,SELLERS,6/2/2014 15:12,$40.00,esponse,chards@lobal.net,,
    [2] => 10488,EmHern,"A HOME FOR YOU,LLC",37749,MILLER,6/1/2014 8:23,$33.00, Response,23@YAHOO.COM,,
)
```

the result I'm expecting is :

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 10264|dan|Dan|$28.40|Dan@Cold.com
        [1] => 10443|Dari|"D. R, LLC"|esponse|chards@lobal.net
        [2] => 10488|EmHern|"A HOME FOR YOU,LLC"|37749|23@YAHOO.COM
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fgetcsv() should handle single quotes, just fine in fact the default output of fputcsv() is to quote ( wrap ) any line with spaces in it. having " " around strings with the delimiter is perfectly expected, "words, other words", that is 100% fine with fgetscsv.

try this

```
echo '<pre>';
    if (($handle = fopen($csvFileName, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (false !== ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1024))) {
print_r($data);
            $data_row = array(
                $data[0],
                $data[1],
                $data[2],
                $data[6],
                $data[8]
            );                            
           $result[] = implode("|", $data_row);
           $row++;
        }               
    }
        fclose($handle);
        return $result;
```

implode is a bit cleaner and you wont need to trim the extra "|" ?, as i see no purpose for it anyway why not just omit the last ( rightmost ) |.

```
   $outPut .="|";                                  
   array_push($result, rtrim($outPut, "|"));


   array_push($result, $outPut));
```

in fact runing your exact code gives me this output?

```
$result = array();
        $row = 1;
        if (($handle = fopen(__DIR__.'/test.csv', "r")) !== FALSE) {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                $outPut = "";
                $outPut .= $data[0];
                $outPut .="|";
                $outPut .= $data[1];
                $outPut .="|";
                $outPut .= $data[2];
                $outPut .="|";
                $outPut .= $data[6];
                $outPut .="|";
                $outPut .= $data[8];
                $outPut .="|";
                array_push($result, rtrim($outPut, "|"));
                $row++;
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);

array(
'0' => '10264|dan|Dan|$28.40|Dan@Cold.com',
'1' => '10443|Dari|D. R, LLC|$40.00|chards@lobal.net',
'2' => '10488|EmHern|A HOME FOR YOU,LLC|$33.00|23@YAHOO.COM'
)
```

running my code gives me

```
array(
'0' => '10264|dan|Dan|$28.40|Dan@Cold.com',
'1' => '10443|Dari|D. R, LLC|$40.00|chards@lobal.net',
'2' => '10488|EmHern|A HOME FOR YOU,LLC|$33.00|23@YAHOO.COM'
)
```

here be your solution

```
echo "<pre>";
$result = array();
        $row = 1;
        if (($handle = fopen(__DIR__.'/test.csv', "r")) !== FALSE) {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                if(count($data) == 1){
                    $f = fopen('php://temp', 'w');
                    fwrite($f, $data[0]);
                    rewind($f);
                    $data = fgetcsv($f, 1000, ",");
                    fclose($f);
                }

                $data_row = array(
                    $data[0],
                    $data[1],
                    $data[2],
                    $data[6],
                    $data[8]
                 );                            
                $result[] = implode("|", $data_row);
                $row++;
            }
        }
        var_export($result);
        fclose($handle);
```

outputs

```
array(
'0' => '10264|dan|Dan|$28.40|Dan@Cold.com',
'1' => '10443|Dari|D. R, LLC|$40.00|chards@lobal.net',
'2' => '10488|EmHern|A HOME FOR YOU,LLC|$33.00|23@YAHOO.COM'
)
```

explination

getcsv returns a single element because of the outer quotes ", but it strips out one set of quotes around the "D. R, LLC" bit ( witch gives us a string similar to line 1), then check for that single element, and write it to the temp buffer, ( stream wrapper ) and reprocess the stream with fgetcsv and voila fixed!

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, can this be fixed please?

Comment: your csv looks fine without counting the columns that is, the "D. R, LLC" is fine.

Comment: sorry i had two rr's in print_r, the print_r will print the data on each row so you can verify the csv is read correctly, the pre tag preserves whitespace and makes it easier to read the print_r output.

Comment: Sorry your code did not fix it, I know my csv is fine but I want to know how can I deal with that in PHP

Comment: with what? specificly, i use fgetcsv all the time with quotes, your output makes no sense even with a hanging " single double quote you wouldn't get that output.

Comment: That is the result i get from your code. except for the quotes, if you want the quotes id use fputcsv with a stream wrapper

Comment: I tested your code and I did not get the same result can you please change your solution to include the full function so I can see what I did wrong please?

Comment: your problem is elsewhere, I ran your exact code ( part inside funtion ) and got the correct results, posted your code I ran only change was the file location, as would be expected. that and i prefer var_export over print_r

Comment: Again, I'm sorry but my code does not give the same result as yours you have a wrong csv data in the file you created to test, here is my csv file https://www.dropbox.com/s/f24oyppez4owd4m/file.csv

Comment: Hi, did you test me csv file?

Comment: see this is not the data you posted previously, "10443,Dari,""D. R, LLC"",37308,SELLERS,6/2/2014 15:12,$40.00,esponse,chards@lobal.net,,"